# How to change a value on a specific field with specific condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, sh

I'm looking if someone can help me modify a specific value on a specific field. A specific example would be like:

```
thissample000     0field2     00field3     11
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     11
thissample000     0field2     00field3     0
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     11
thissample000     0field2     00field3     0
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     0
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     11
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     11
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     0
thissample000     0field2     00field3     0
thissample000     0field2     00field3     11
thissample000     0field2     00field3     11
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     11
field1sample0     0field2     00field3     0
thissample000     0field2     00field3     11
```

From the above, I need to modify only the field 4 (4th column) with value of 0 but only if field 1(1st column) is thissample000.
I cannot use sed command as all the fields have 0 character and I cannot manually edit it as there are thousands of lines.
seeking for your kind help. This is via LINUX btw.

Thanks!

Comment: Add specific shell or tool tag, like bash or sh or sed or awk or C. `linux` is just an operating system. Can you post example output achieved from the input you provided? I fail to understand where "field 4" is. You meant 4th column?

Comment: is this vim??............

Comment: yes Kamil, 4th column.

Comment: I'm failing to understand where the NULL characters are ... can you add a hex dump?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`, this seems to be pretty straight forward:

```
awk '$1=="thissample000"{$4="0"}1' file
```

But this reformats the output. So we need gawk with its `split` implementation:

```
awk '$1=="thissample000"{split($0, a, FS, seps); a[4]="0"; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", a[i], seps[i]);print"";next}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you Steffen, can I use a wildcard * for the condition '$1=="*specific_keyword*" ? This is because for field 1 (1st column) there further more characters involve and all have different values but have same keyword.

Comment: You need to formulate a regex. *any character* for instance would be `.*`.

Comment: Ok I found a good regex as i need to filter out they keyword=video
regex would be

$1 ~ /video/

answer is c/o steeldriver